# Geometrical meaning of the condition $\int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} \omega f(r\omega) d\omega = 0$, $r>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Given a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, what is the geometric  meaning of the condition $$\int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} \omega f(r\omega) d\omega = 0,$$ for $r>0$? And what are examples of smooth functions that satisfy this conditions?

Comment: On the example part: First, being pedantic, if $\text{supp}(f)\subset B_r(0)$ then the integral is zero since $f(r\omega)=0$ for every $\omega\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. More generally any even function will satisfy your condition.

Comment: Is this for all $r>0$ or some $r>0$?